# Effective addressing in Real Mode - accessing array

Tags: x86-16

I am working in real mode of x86 and say I need to access a element from the array *people*; the index of which is in the register **BX**.

```
   MOV BX, 2

   struc person
    .name resb 11
    .age  resb 1
   endstruc

   people: times 10 db person_size
```

The effective addressing in real mode is limited to `base + offset`. So code like

`mov [people + bx * person_size + person.age],byte 20`

does not work; however the assembler can do the calculation if no **BX** register is used -

`mov [people + 2 * person_size + person.age],byte 20`

I can do multiplication or shift lefts a few times and make it work, but is there a way to do access any element in an array, without assuming that the size of the structure will remain the same in future?

Is there any other way than multiplying like below (cannot do shifts if the structure size changes, code will also change)?

```
    push ax
        mov ax, person_size
        mul bx
        mov bx, ax
    pop ax
    add bx, person.age
    mov [people + bx], byte 20
```

Comment: Use `si` and `di` registers when working with arrays, where each element stores the offset address of each element. You can then access the ith element's address as `[si + i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The effective addressing in real mode is limited to base + offset.

Only on 8086 but not on x86-16 in general.

It's true that in Real Mode you can use Scaled Index addressing  like in Fifoernik's answer, but in your program it won't help much since the Scale values are limited to either {1, 2, 4, or 8} and your structure has 12 bytes.

You must do the multiplication yourself especially since you want to leave it open what the size of the structure will be in future.

> ```
> push ax
>     mov ax, person_size
>     mul bx
>     mov bx, ax
> pop ax
> add bx, person.age
> mov [people + bx], byte 20
> ```

What the Real Mode on x86-16 does offer is an extra `imul` variant that simplifies your calculation:

```
imul bx, person_size
mov  [people + bx + person.age], byte 20
```

- There was no need to add *person.age* in a separate instruction. The assembler will add *people* and *person.age* to become a 16-bit offset.
- Your version with the `mul bx` instruction also modified the `DX` register. you didn't preserve that one like you did with `AX`!

For a true 8086 your code was (almost) fine:

```
push ax
push dx
mov  ax, person_size
mul  bx
mov  bx, ax
pop  dx
pop  ax
mov  [people + bx + person.age], byte 20
```

---

One optimization would pad the 12-byte structure to 16 bytes.

```
struc person
 .name resb 11
 .age  resb 1
 .pad  resb 4
endstruc
```

This replaces multiplication by simple shifting to the left in order to access the elements:

For x86-16 (array index in `ebx`):

```
shl ebx, 1
mov [people + ebx * 8 + person.age], byte 20
```

or for 8086 (array index in `bx`):

```
push cx
mov  cl, 4
shl  bx, cl
pop  cx
mov  [people + bx + person.age], byte 20
```

Another solution uses a lookup table to avoid multiplication and padding.

```
LUT  dw 0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108   ; 10 elements
...
shl  bx, 1               ; Lookup table holds words
mov  bx, [LUT + bx]      ; Fetch array element's offset
mov  [people + bx + person.age], byte 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, it is much clear now. One question tough, except for the prefix byte when using 32 bit registers in Real mode, is it bad practice to use 32 bit registers in Real Mode. I understand, that sometimes it can come handy, but until now I have never used then in Real mode programs.

Comment: @ArjobMukherjee It's almost never bad practice to use 32 bit registers in Real Mode. Not only do they make life much easier (increased storage capacity, more addressing modes, ...), many a time using 32-bit registers will make the code run much faster. IMO there's only the drawback of the increased code size due to the Operand Size Prefix and/or Address Size Prefix.